# Grails: composite key with cascade causes error when saving object

Tags: grails

I have two domain classes, A and B. A has a composite key. One part of it points to B. I want to set cascade:'all' for that field:

**A.groovy**

```
class A implements Serializable {        
    Integer a = 1 // This points to another class in my real code. I tried to make it as simple as possible. It has the same effect.
    B b

    static mapping = {
        // It works fine if I comment out the following line (i.e. no composite key)
        id composite:['a', 'b']        
        b cascade: 'all'
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof A)) {
            return false
        }
        other.a == a && other.b == b
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append a
        builder.append b
        builder.toHashCode()
    }
}
```

**B.groovy**

```
class B {
    String name = "Test"
}
```

When I try to run the following code in Bootstrap.groovy, I get an exception:

```
B b = new B()
// It works fine if the next line is uncommented
//b.save(failOnError:true)

A a = new A()
a.b = b
a.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

The error:

```
| Error 2013-09-05 16:53:35,308 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   13 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    308 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    301 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I know using composite keys is discouraged but I'd really like to know what's the problem here.

Comment: `cascade` behavior would work on associations but in your case you have `B` defined in `A` which would create `b_id` (say) column in table `A`. You can either use `static belongsTo = [A]` in `B` to get the cascade nature instead of `cascade all` in `A`.

Comment: I removed the `cascade all` and added `static belongsTo = [A]`, but I get the same error. Again, it works when I don't use a composite key.